# Embed custom JS app in Joomla MVC

Tags: custom-component, mvc, angularjs

A before warning: I'm new to both Joomla, PHP and JS. So this might be obvious, but I'm lost.

I'm looking to embed a program I made in react/node into Joomla.
The program uses JSX to create the HTML elements, then those elements are used as input for the rest of the app.

I've done research and found that it's best to make a custom MVC

- [StackOverflow angularJS app in joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365907/how-to-integrate-angularjs-app-inside-joomla)
- [StackExchange of the same question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8862/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-structure-a-joomla-3-custom-component-view-using)

I've developed a basic MVC with admin and site files, by following https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Introduction.

There isn't much information on how to then get the JS scripts running on the MVC, and which files would be the input from the user.

How do I get the JS scripts to run?

If I can, where do I redirect the JSX to run to create the input forms?

Would it be best to redevelop the app in angular?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback from our volunteers.

Comment: Are you able to share some of the code that you have already got as there is not enough information in your question to know where you are at with your understanding of creating a joomla component( we don't call components MVC). I would think your JS should be in a /media/com_yourthing folder and in com_yourthing/views/my/view/default.php you have a $document  = Factory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/com_yourthing/js/yourthing.js'); but that doesn't solve how to autorun your script.

Comment: Without any detail about your scripts, maybe you don't need to use the default.php and you just want view.html.php to let your JS build the HTML for your page. My JS experience is limited to a couple of small hacks so maybe someone else can offer more experienced knowledge.

Comment: I can't share code as its for work. 
The JS scripts are written in react, the HTML portion is pushed from the scripts using JSX. JSX creates the user input for the program (text boxes, forms). The information is then passed into the program. Then after the program parses the data, the results are passed back onto the page.

It relies on using DIVs and element IDs to show and take the data from the correct elements.

As for the MVC component, I just have the basics down, e.g. views and menu.
I've using the Hello_world component linked in the docs as reference and as a prototype test.